# postgres insert random number into array column

Tags: arrays, postgresql

So I have an array column on a table that has type int. I am load testing for a million rows and need four array elements per record all with different values.

```
INSERT INTO contacts (numbers)
SELECT '{4443331111, 2223334444, 2223339999, 8887779999}'
  FROM generate_series(1,2) AS x(id);
```

This creates 2 records but I need the numbers to be unique.

Comment: Incidentally, guessing from the name of your table, are those phone numbers? If so, you probably don't want to store them as integers, as phone numbers can have leading zeroes, which will mysteriously disappear in an integer column. (It's common outside North America for area codes to start with 0 to distinguish from local numbers, and 00 often represents international dialling)

Comment: Thanks for the input but this is merely an example. No actual data was harmed in the asking of this question :)

Comment: You are using `contacts (numbers)` for your example - you should be using `TEXT`, not `INTEGER` as your type. One doesn't add, subtract, multiply or divide telephone numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO contacts (numbers)
SELECT distinct array[
        (random() * 99999999)::integer,
        (random() * 99999999)::integer,
        (random() * 99999999)::integer,
        (random() * 99999999)::integer
    ]
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x(id);
```

Notice that the number 8887779999 is out of range for integer. So perhaps you want biginteger.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the `random()` function, multiplied by some suitable number to give your maximum value; but you need to construct an array from four calls to that function.

There is a slightly different syntax for constructing array values which will be easier to work with here, which looks like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY[4443331111, 2223334444, 2223339999, 8887779999]
```

Since you don't need to build it up as a string, you can use a function call for the parts of the array, meaning this should work:

```
SELECT ARRAY[random() * 1000000, random() * 1000000, random() * 1000000, random() * 1000000]
FROM generate_series(1,2) AS x(id);
```

Since `random()` returns a floating point number and you want an integer, you need a cast somewhere. The easiest to write is to cast the whole array with a `::int[]` at the end, like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY[random() * 1000000, random() * 1000000, random() * 1000000, random() * 1000000]::int[]
FROM generate_series(1,2) AS x(id);
```

Postgres Docs: [`random()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html); [array constructors (including note on the casting shortcut)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS)